# Change observations in a variable SAS

Tags: variables, sas

I have the following dataset:

```
area    areaname
10354   Texas
35235   Ohio
35113   California
US352   Illinois
23535   Delaware
US664   Kentucky
US321   Ohio
13355   New York
```

I want to modify the following observations:

Change

```
US352 to US35235
US664 to US66451
US321 to US32190
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use an `if` statement, e.g, `if area = "US352 then area ="US35235"`

Comment: I did try that, it doesn't work. All it does is create a new column for each of those observations.

Comment: Did you make sure to ensure the values inside quotes? This lets SAS know its a character observation, if you don't use quotes around the values SAS will assume you are referencing a variable.

Comment: Please edit the question, to show the code you tried.  That will help others see why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tranwrd` function to replace:

```
area = Tranwrd(area,'US352','US35235');
```